# Find oldest non-conflicting ancestor commit

Tags: git

I want to find the oldest commit in the history of a main development branch that can be used as starting point for a bug fix branch.

Typically I create a bug fix on a branch started from the current development branch. However sometimes I need to apply a bug fix to older releases (tagged commits). But I cannot merge the bug fix branch into a "patch release branch" that has been started from a release tag, because the bug fix branch has been started from a newer commit. I know I can cherry-pick the fix commits but sometimes that's not as easy as merging a branch would be.

I could merge the bug fix branch into a patch release branch if I had used an older commit as starting point for the bug fix branch. Is there a way to find a "good" starting commit that is as old as it could be without any conflicts with the bug fix.

For the answer please assume that the bug fix already exists as a commit and I want to rewrite it to have an older parent but the same patch diff.